# how to return a .htm page as a view from controller action

Tags: asp.net, jquery

in my .aspx page i have something like this:

```
    <select id="seltemp" onchange="calltemp()">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select Template</option>
<option value="1">Template1</option>
<option value="2">Template2</option>
<option value="3">Template3</option>
<option value="4">Html Template</option>
</select>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function calltemp() {
            document.getElementById('datashow').innerHTML = "";


            var id = (document.getElementById('seltemp').value);
            if (id != 0) {debugger;
                $.get("/Templates/Select/" + id + "/", function(result) {

                    $("#Renderthisdiv").html(result);
                });
            }
        }         
    </script>
```

and in TemplatesController

```
public ActionResult Select(int id)
    {
        ......
        ......
        return View("/Views/Templates/Temp1.htm");

    }
```

please help me to render Temp1.htm page into "Renderthisdiv" div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return File("~/Views/Templates/Temp1.htm", "text/html");
```

-- Modified

Comment: it gives error saying
no overload for 'File'  takes 1 arguments

Comment: Sorry for that, try this:

return File("~/Views/Templates/Temp1.htm", "text/html");